# Assistance required with filter graph construction(fast motion between times)

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to re-create the following video, using ffmpeg.
https://youtu.be/eVQ9ysp0Pj0. "please check 0.19 minute for examples"
I have the following line of code which has most of the elements, except the part where is applies fast motion for 1s at certain outputs([vfr1][vfr2][vfr3])/times. currently it is only setpts=0.5*PTS[vboom] for the entire length of the video.

`exe = "-i " + file + " -i " + frame + " -i " + framestart + " -i " + frameEnd + " -i " + audioOverlay + " -filter_complex \"[0:v]pad="+mVideoWidth+":"+mVideoHeight+":576:0[vpad]; [vpad][1]overlay[vframed]; [vframed]split=3[vfr1][vfr2][vfr3]; [vfr1]reverse[vrev]; [vfr2][vrev][vfr3]concat=n=3,setpts=0.5*PTS[vboom]; [vboom][2]overlay=enable='lte(t,2)'[vpreout]; [vpreout][3]overlay=enable='gte(t,"+msec+"*3*0.5-2)' \" -map 4:a -b:v 8000k -shortest -preset ultrafast -crf 23 " + file2.getAbsolutePath();`

i have tried the following code snippets in various sections of the filter graph, with no luck!

//[0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[0:v]trim=2:5,setpts=2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];[0:v]trim=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];
//[0:v]trim=0:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vfr1];[0:v]trim=10:30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vfr2];[0:v]trim=start=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vfr3];
//[0:v]trim=2:3,setpts=0.75*(PTS-STARTPTS); [0:v]trim=4:5,setpts=0.75*(PTS-STARTPTS); [0:v]trim=7:8,setpts=0.75*(PTS-STARTPTS);
//[0:v]select='between(t,1,4)+between(t,4,6)',setpts=0.87*PTS;

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trim and setpts is on the right track.

e.g.

```
[0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
[0:v]trim=2:5,setpts=2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];
[0:v]trim=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];
[v1][v2][v3]concat=n=3[vboom]
```

In this snippet, v2 will be sped up.

Comment: [vframed]split=3[vfr1][vfr2][vfr3]; [vfr1]reverse[vrev]; [0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vfr2]; [0:v]trim=2:5,setpts=2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[vrev]; [0:v]trim=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vfr3]; [vfr2][vrev][vfr3]concat=n=3[vboom]; [vboom][2]overlay=enable='lte(t,2)'[vpreout]; [vpreout][3]overlay=enable='gte(t,"+msec+"*3*0.5-2)' i tried the following but it does not complete, it fails, giving Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share link to report.

Comment: i dont have a link to the project, i am  running it locally i android java using ffmpeg kit

Comment: as soon as i remove 0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vfr2]; [0:v]trim=2:5,setpts=2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[vrev]; [0:v]trim=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vfr3]; it works

Comment: Error filter setpts has an unconnected output

Comment: Paste the full command you tried in your Q.